# How to merge two Firebase accounts (one created with email and another one with phone number)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

This is the scenario:

1. User signs up using email and password (account 1 is created)
2. User logs out
3. User signs up using phone number (account 2 is created)
4. User is prompted to enter an email and password to complete registration
5. User enters the same email and password as before

How can I, as the app developer, delete account 2 and link the phone number to account 1 without making the user go through the phone validation process again?

Comment: Why would ask the user to enter email and pass since it is already authenticated with the phone number?

Comment: Business rule ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a function that checks if the email is registered before.

Then, link the number to the email without verification and delete the user account created with the phone number.

Comment: Is it really possible to set a user's phone number outside the verification flow? Can you tell me where I can find more info on this?